# Asterisk not sending media packets using music on hold

Tags: asterisk

My asterisk version is 1.4.22. I am trying to Dial to a third party using asterisk using music on hold.
When I called, on its console it showed 'started music on hold', however, I didn't heard anything . When I took a wireshark trace I found asterisk was not sending any media packets . Below is a trace taken at console :

-- Started music on hold, class 'default', on SIP/test-b73eb410

-- SIP/LocalCarrierOut-b76a75c8 is ringing

-- SIP/LocalCarrierOut-b76a75c8 is ringing

-- Stopped music on hold on SIP/test-b73eb410

My .conf file :

[CodeTest]

exten = 1234,1,Answer()

exten = 1234,n,wait(1)

exten = 1234,n,Dial(SIP/1234@LocalCarrierOut,,rm)

Thanks

Himanshu

Answer (score 0):

Very likly you have no moh classes.

For more info see /etc/asterisk/musiconhold.conf or do

```
asterisk -rx "moh show files "
```